# xarray temporal averaging only if time period has minimum amount of samples

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray, resample

I'm resampling a daily xarray dataset into monthly values. Is there a straightforward way to output NaN when for example only 50 percent of the days have valid data?

In the moment I'm using the xarray standard function which will output a monthly average regardless of the number of valid days: `ds.resample(time='1MS').mean(dim='time')`

Comment: you could count the number of `NaN`s and set pixels that have a count > 50% to `NaN` themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataArrayResample.map`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.resample.DataArrayResample.map.html#xarray.core.resample.DataArrayResample.map) to apply a custom reduction while resampling:

```py
def nan50_mean(da):
    return da.mean(dim='time').where(
        da.notnull().sum(dim='time') >= len(da.time) * 0.5
    )

ds.resample(time='1MS').map(nan50_mean)
```